# Should the subsets of the universe necessary cover graphically, when added together, the full universe, or not.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to rigourously illustrate graphically a partition of an universe set : should the subsets of the universe necessary cover graphically, when added together, the full universe, or not.

For example, let's assume that universe $\Omega$ is made only of a subset $A$ and a subset $B$ :

Is the left schematic mathematically correct ?
Or should we only have the right to draw it as the right example ?

[image]

Comment: See [Partition of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set): "a grouping of its elements into non-empty subsets, in such a way that every element is included in exactly one subset."

Comment: yes, but this does not tell if the left schematic is *correct* or not.

Comment: (I could decide to put elements only in A and B of the left schematic)

Comment: Maybe useful: [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Overview) : "In Venn diagrams, a shaded zone may represent an empty zone."